# How to change background image in mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I am developing a simple html page with a background image.On a desktop, the background is displaying perfectly but I am trying to change the background image on a mobile device.

The html and css is as follows :

**HTML**

```
<div class="pc-img" ></div>
<div class="mobile-img" ></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body
{
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.pc-img {
     min-height: 95% !important;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://www.laminaresearchcenter.com/images/comingsoon.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
}

.mobile-img
{
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 384px) {

.mobile-img
    {
         background: url('http://www.outbarga.in/images/comingsoon.jpg');

       visibility: visible;
}

.pc-img
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need 2 class and 2 divs to do this.
You can set @media queries for one div, and change his properties.

**CSS:**

```
.pc-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: #000;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .pc-img {
    background: purple;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .pc-img {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```

Look this demo: <kbd>[Demo 1](https://jsfiddle.net/zzrcscjp/)</kbd>

Btw, if you want two divs, make this: <kbd>[Demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/zzrcscjp/1/)</kbd>

```
.pc-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: #000;
}
.device-img {
  background: steelblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .device-img {
    display: block;
  }
  .pc-img {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .device-img {
    display: block;
  }
  .pc-img {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Ferrrmolina, Your code is working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

You must give `display:block`to `mobile-img` class and  `display:none` to `pc-img` class in media query

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 384px) {  
    .mobile-img
        {
           display: block;
           background: url('http://www.outbarga.in/images/comingsoon.jpg');
           visibility: visible;  
    }
    .pc-img {
         display: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Responsive page

```css
body
{
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.pc-img {
     min-height: 95% !important;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://www.laminaresearchcenter.com/images/comingsoon.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
}

.mobile-img
{
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 384px) {

.mobile-img
    {
         background: url('http://www.outbarga.in/images/comingsoon.jpg');

       display: block;
}

.pc-img
{
    display: none;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="pc-img" ></div>
<div class="mobile-img" ></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `display:none` and `display:block` property in stead of `visibility`

```
.mobile-img{display:none;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 384px) {  
.mobile-img {
   display: block;
   background-image: url('http://www.outbarga.in/images/comingsoon.jpg');
}
.pc-img {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make it `background-image` instead of just `background`

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 384px) {
    .mobile-img
    {
       background-image: url('http://www.outbarga.in/images/comingsoon.jpg'); 
       visibility: visible;
    }
}
```